# If $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,2]$ and $f(1) = -1$ , $f(2)=1$ then there must be a point $x$ in $[0,1]$ where $f(x) = 0$

Tags: functions, problem-solving

> If $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,2]$ and $f(1) = -1$ ,  $f(2)=1$ then there must be a point $x$ in $[0,1]$ where $f(x) = 0$.

Is it true or false? Can you justify if true?

Comment: This is *false*.  Consider any $f$ which is constant on $[0,1]$.

Comment: The IMHO most obvious counterexample: The linear function determined by those values. It has positive slope (because $f(2)>f(1)$) and is negative at $1$, thus it must be negative for all $x\le 1$, in particular in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true . The intermediate value theorem guarantees $f(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,2]$ but $f(x)=0$ might no happen  in [$0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(1)=-1 \leq 0 \leq f(2)=1 $, and $f$ continuous , by the intermediate values theorem since there is $x \in [0,2]$ such that $f(x)=0$

Comment: I understand temptation to apply the intermediate value theorem, but please see my comment or another answer to know why the conclusion of the question is *false*.

Comment: I tought it was a typo , yes  the IVT doesn't garantie that $x$ is in $[0,1]$ without having any more information on $f$